# Differential equation: Substance in body

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem:

A substance is eaten by a person at a constant rate *a* [milligrams per hour] . Let *y* [milligrams] denote the amount of the substance in the body after *t* hours, and let *b* [milligrams] denote the starting amount of the substance in the body (i.e *y(0)=b*). The substance exits the body at a speed proportional to the current amount of the substance in the body.

**1) Create a differential equation that describes this.**

I've tried the following:

1)  $ y=at-k\frac{dy} {dt} $ with the condition $y(0)=b$

I'm however not sure if this is the correct way to create an equation that describes the relation stated above, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: Not exactly. The rate of substance in the body is the net flow of intake versus exiting body. So the rate equation would be $\frac{dy}{dt} = -\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)_{\mathrm{out}} + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)_{\mathrm{in}} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a small time $dt$, the person will ingest $a\, dt$ of substance and will expel $k\, y\, dt$ of the substance. So $dy = a\, dt - k\, y\, dt$, or ${dy\over dt} = a - ky$.

Often when setting up differential equations, it helps to begin "In a small time $dt\dots$." Then construct the infinitesimal changes $dy$ in the dependent variable. Then divide through by $dt$ to form the differential equation.

Note that my "$k$" is different from yours (the units are different).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially for generalising about constructing differential equations.